# MySQL Query limiting results by sub table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really struggling with this query and I hope somebody can help.

I am querying across multiple tables to get the dataset that I require. The following query is an anonymised version:

```
SELECT  main_table.id, 
        sub_table_1.field_1, 
        main_table.field_1, 
        main_table.field_2, 
        main_table.field_3, 
        main_table.field_4, 
        main_table.field_5, 
        main_table.field_6, 
        main_table.field_7,
        sub_table_2.field_1,
        sub_table_2.field_2,
        sub_table_2.field_3,
        sub_table_3.field_1,
        sub_table_4.field_1,
        sub_table_4.field_2
FROM main_table
INNER JOIN sub_table_4 ON sub_table_4.id = main_table.id
INNER JOIN sub_table_2 ON sub_table_2.id = main_table.id
INNER JOIN sub_table_3 ON sub_table_3.id = main_table.id
INNER JOIN sub_table_1 ON sub_table_1.id = main_table.id
WHERE sub_table_4.field_1 = '' AND sub_table_4.field_2 = '0' AND sub_table_2.field_1 != ''
```

The query works, the problem I have is sub_table_1 has a revision number (int 11). Currently I get duplicate records with different revision numbers and different versions of sub_table_1.field_1 which is to be expected, but I want to limit the result set to only include results limited by the latest revision number, giving me only the latest sub_table_1_field_1 and I really can not figure it out!

Can anybody lend me a hand?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

It's always important to remember that a `JOIN` can be on a subquery as well as a table.  You could build a subquery that returns the results you want to see then, once you've got the data you want, join it in the parent query.

It's hard to 'tailor' an answer that's specific to you problem, as it's too obfuscated (as you admit) to know what the data and tables really look like, but as an example:

Say `table1` has four fields:  `id`, `revision_no`, `name` and `stuff`.  You want to return a distinct list of `name` values, with their latest version of `stuff` (which, we'll pretend varies by revision).  You could do this in isolation as:

```
select t.* from table1 t 
 inner join
  (SELECT name, max(revision_no) maxr
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY name) mx
     on mx.name = t.name 
     and mx.maxr = t.revision_no;
```

*(Note:  see fiddle at the end)*

That would return each individual `name` with the latest revision of `stuff`.

Once you've got that nailed down, you could then swap out

```
INNER JOIN sub_table_1 ON sub_table_1.id = main_table.id
```

....with....

```
INNER JOIN (select t.* from table1 t 
 inner join
  (SELECT name, max(revision_no) maxr
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY name) mx
     on mx.name = t.name 
     and mx.maxr = t.revision_no) sub_table_1 
   ON sub_table_1.id = main_table.id
```

...which would allow a `join` with a recordset that is more tailored to that which you want to join (again, don't get hung up on the actual query I've used, it's just there to demonstrate the method).

There may well be more elegant ways to achieve this, but it's sometimes good to start with a simple solution that's easier to replicate, then simplify it once you've got the general understanding of the what and why nailed down.

Hope that helps - as I say, it's as specific as I could offer without having an idea of the real data you're using.

(for the sake of reference, [here is a fiddle with a working version of the above example query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0e4ed/1))

Comment: It couldn't be a 'working version' - unless we have quite different understandings of 'working' - which is a shame because it started off well. :-(

Comment: Why?  The fiddle demonstrates an arbitrary query that uses a join to return the rows with a "max" value.  It does what it intends to do, thus 'working'

Comment: You're returning indeterminate values for id and stuff

Comment: In the fiddle? No it isn't. I'd suggest you revise it again.

Answer (score 0):

In your case where you only need one column from the table, make this a subquery in your select clause instead of than a join. You get the latest revision by ordering by revision number descending and limiting the result to one row.

```
SELECT  
  main_table.id, 
  (
    select sub_table_1.field_1 
    from sub_table_1 
    where sub_table_1.id = main_table.id
    order by revision_number desc
    limit 1
  ) as sub_table_1_field_1,
  main_table.field_1, 
  ...
FROM main_table
INNER JOIN sub_table_4 ON sub_table_4.id = main_table.id
INNER JOIN sub_table_2 ON sub_table_2.id = main_table.id
INNER JOIN sub_table_3 ON sub_table_3.id = main_table.id
WHERE sub_table_4.field_1 = '' 
  AND sub_table_4.field_2 = '0' 
  AND sub_table_2.field_1 != '';
```